# How do I make my social media links appear site wide on additional html pages?

Tags: html, css

The issue I'm experiencing is so simple it's confusing me...
I've implemented my social media logo as links. They work completely fine on the index page, just not elsewhere. I've essentially copied and pasted the exact code below to the remaining html pages, and nothing. The code isn't responsive. Please see examples below.

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56lkd.png)
[resume.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3FKp.png)

Here is my code...

```css
.socialBanner {
  position: absolute;
}

.githubLogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  top: -1260px;
  left: 185px;
}

.linkedinLogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  top: -1260px;
  left: 265px;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialBanner">
  <a href="https://github.com/thesd5x"><img src="githubLogo.png" alt="githubLogo" class="githubLogo"></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordan-fichter-a40762152/"><img src="linkedinLogo.png" alt="linkedinLogo" class="linkedinLogo"></a>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

As stated below, I've tried copy and pasting the code as well as reviewing it line by line, and I'm not sure what I'm missing exactly. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing a code sample where it's not working, but I'm guessing it's related to the `top: -1260px;` pushing the logos completely off screen.  Try not to depend so much on absolute positioning, it leads to exactly this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a positioning issue. Remove all your positioning code and you’re good to go.

```css
img {width: 64px;}
```

```html
<div class="socialBanner">
  <a href="https://github.com/thesd5x"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25231.png" alt="githubLogo" class="githubLogo"></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordan-fichter-a40762152/"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/LinkedIn_icon_circle.svg/1200px-LinkedIn_icon_circle.svg.png" alt="linkedinLogo" class="linkedinLogo"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I cannot think of a reason to use `top: -1260px` for social icons other than some animation moving them in from 'above'.

I have somewhat replicated the example image showing three icons below the byline. As you can see in the snippet CSS, with careful planning of *flexbox* elements and proper alignment you can have a responsive 'banner' without media queries.

- The left side of the banner `.me` is a vertical flexbox container with three rows of which `.socialBanner` is a flexbox row container.
- The right side of the banner `.menu` is a horizontal flexbox container with four menu options.

Upon resizing the browser, the *flexbox* alignment and wrapping options make the banner neatly fit in viewports `>= 320px` wide.

Check out the little math in `html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }` which calculates the root `font-size` relative to the minimum viewport size (`vmin`) resulting in:

- `font-size: 14px` on 320px viewport minimum size devices
- `font-size: 20px` on 1280px viewport minimum size devices
- All other font sizes are calculated relative to the current viewport minimum size. Effectively: for each `160px` change in viewport size, the font size changes `0.25px`
- Math: linear equation **y = mx + b** for points **p1(320,14)** and **p2(1280,20)** => *y = 0.00625x + 12* converted to CSS using `100vmin` for **x** and `0.75rem` for **b** (which is `12 / 16 = 0.75rem`).

**BTW** *site wide* will still require you to copy the code to each individual html file unless you use some framework that does the copying automatically...

**Snippet**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap');

*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box }

/* Linear equation y=mx+b using points p1(320,14) p2(1280,20) */
html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }

body {
    margin: 0;                          /* remove default spacing */

    display: grid; place-items: center; /* Easy centering demo banner */
    width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;     /* at least full screen */

    font-size: 1rem;                    /* inherit responsive root font */
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;

    background-color: #222222; color: White;
    cursor: default;
}

a { text-decoration: none; color: currentColor }

.main-banner {
    width: 100%; min-height: 40vh;
    padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
    background-color: #c1e1c1;
}

/* horizontal orientation */
.main-banner, .me, .menu, .socialBanner {
    /* Flexbox layout */
    display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;

    /* Flexbox alignment */
    align-items: center;

    /* text alignment */
    text-align: center;
}
/* vertical orientation */
.me { flex-direction: column }

/* Flexbox alignment specifics */
.socialBanner     { justify-content: center }
.main-banner      { justify-content: space-around  }
.menu, .me        { justify-content: space-between }

.me > *           { width: 100%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold }
.name             { font-size: 3.5em ; line-height: 1 }
.byline           { font-size: 1.25em; line-height: 2 }
.socialBanner a   { display: block; padding: 1rem 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem } 

.socialBanner img {
    display: block; /* removes tiny whitespace below images */
    border-radius: 50%
} 


.menu             { color: #b5b5b7; font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: bold }
.menu > *         { border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; flex: 1; padding: 1rem; cursor: pointer }
.menu > :hover    { border-bottom: 1px solid White; color: White }
```

```html
<div class="main-banner">
    <div class="me">
        <div class="name"  >jordan fichter</div>
        <div class="byline">portfolio + ux design + web development</div>

        <div class="socialBanner">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/thesd5x"><img src="https://picsum.photos/40?random=1" alt="githubLogo" class="githubLogo"></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordan-fichter-a40762152/"><img src="https://picsum.photos/40?random=2" alt="linkedinLogo" class="linkedinLogo"></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com"><img src="https://picsum.photos/40?random=3" alt="googleLogo" class="googleLogo"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <div>welcome</div>
        <div>resume </div>
        <div>about  </div>
        <div>contact</div>
    </div>
</div>
```